# Router - can't set default route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

The following code doesn't automatically display the listing, I have to create a link and click through. Can anyone please help?

Thank you

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/http';
import { CourseListComponent } from '../lists/course.list';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
import EndPointService  from '../../Services/EndPointService';
import {CourseDetailsComponent} from '../course.details';


@Component({
    selector: 'course-router-app',
    templateUrl: '/Admin/App/views/router/course-router-app.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        EndPointService
    ]
})
    @RouteConfig([
        { path: '/', name: 'Courses', component: CourseListComponent, useAsDefault: true },
        { path: '/details/:id', name: 'CourseDetails', component: CourseDetailsComponent }
])
export default class CourseRouterComponent {
}
```

Course List Component

```
import { Component, View, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
import { NgFor } from 'angular2/common';
import EndPointService  from '../../Services/EndPointService';
import LogService  from '../../Services/LogService';
import * as dtos from '../../view-models/ICourseViewModel';
import {Router, RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'course-list',
    providers: [EndPointService, LogService],
    templateUrl: '/Admin/App/views/lists/course-list.html'
})
export class CourseListComponent implements OnInit {
    public courses: dtos.ISimpleCourseViewModel[];

    constructor(private _endPointService: EndPointService, private _router: Router, private _logService: LogService) {

    }


    showDetails(course: dtos.ISimpleCourseViewModel) {
        this._logService.log('showing details ' + course.ID);
        this._router.navigate(['CourseDetails', { id: course.ID }]);
    }

    ngOnInit(): any {
        this._endPointService.getAllCoursesSimple().subscribe(
            (response) => {
                this.courses = this.courses = response.json();
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });

    }

    public diagnostic(): string {
        return JSON.stringify(this.courses);
    }
}
```

Also I have `<base href="/">` set.

I have no added the views as I don't think they are important. Can anyone help? I can't see how my code differs from examples online that render default routes.

Comment: This code looks ok. What's your `CourseListComponent` like?

Comment: have you added `<base href="/">` on index.html?

Comment: You must put `CourseListComponent` code here.

Comment: Updated. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an FYI I worked around this issue with the following code - it's a small hack:

```
constructor(private _router: Router) {  }

    ngOnInit(): any {
        this._router.navigate(['Courses']);
    }
```